# Differentiation confusion

Tags: calculus, intuition

I've been reading my textbook, and it tells me how to go about differentiating from first principles, it goes something like this:

$\eqalign{
  & \mathop {\lim }\limits_{h \to 0} {{f(x + h) - f(x)} \over {(x + h) - x}}  \cr 
  & \mathop {\lim }\limits_{h \to 0} {{f(x + h) - f(x)} \over h} \cr} $

The thing that confuses me is as H tends to zero shouldn't the whole thing become undefined? as the denominator becomes so small as to be negligible?
I guess this may arise out of some misunderstanding of limits that I have, I seem to be on very dodgy footing with this whole topic, I'd really appreciate it if someone could help elucidate things a little. Thank you.

Comment: This is the definition of the derivative.

Comment: Thank you for your insight

Comment: To actually differentiate a given function $f(x)$, you need to use express $f(x + h)$, in terms of the given function, etc before evaluating the limit. Then you'll find if $h$ cancels out, etc. and can evaluate the limit, accordingly.

Comment: Yes, this is an indeterminate form. A function is by definition differentiable if this indeterminate form has a limit. You know that some indeterminate forms happen to have limits, right? For instance $\frac{(3+h)^2-9}{h}$ tends to $6$ as $h$ tends to $0$. This can be done by simple algebra. Just observe the difference of squares and factorize. So this says precisely that $f(x)=x^2$ is differentiable at $3$ with derivative $f'(3)=6$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would be easy to think in terms of sequences. As $h$ approaches zero, you have a sequence of differential coefficients. The derivative is the value to which this sequence converges.

You are right in saying that the fraction is undefined when $h$ = $0$ . However, that's not how we do it. We generate a sequence of differential coefficients for $h$ $\neq$ $0$ - note that this is an infinite sequence, since $h$ goes through an infinity of values as it approaches $0$ - and then we see to which value this sequence converges.

The exact value of the differential coefficient when $h = 0$ is irrelevant, because we can't measure the instantaneous rate of change exactly. We can only look at the ***average*** rate of change in an interval around the point of concern and calculate the ***bound***(the value to which the sequence of differential coefficients converges) of this average rate of change.

As an example, consider the function $x^2$. It's differential coefficient is $2x + h$. When we say that its derivative is $2x$, what we mean is *not* that the value of the differential coefficient when $h = 0$, is $2x$ (In fact, this would be a meaningless statement, because the differential coefficient is defined over an *interval* and not at a point.), but that the differential coefficient is bounded by the value $2x$, as $h$ approaches $0$.

Answer (score 3):

The whole idea of the derivative is figuring out the rate of change (slope) of a function at an instant. If you recall the conventional definition of a slope as rise over run, then the idea here is starting from $x$, we take smaller and smaller intervals of $[x, x+h]$ and calculate the slope until $h$ is nearly $0$. When $h$ is actually $0$, there is no interval, so of course the slope is undefined, but as we approach $0$ we can approximate the instantaneous rate of change.

A good overview of limits can be found [here](http://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/Classes/CalcI/limitsIntro.aspx).

Answer (score 2):

That fraction will only be undefined as h=0, which is very different to saying that h tends to 0. Other than when h=0, there is never any reason to consider it negligible to the point of considering it 0. For motivation of that, consider that as x decreases, $\frac 1 x$ increases - the denominator certainly isn't becoming negligible.

Recall the definition of a limit. $\lim_{h=0}$ does not ask what happens when h=0.

Answer (score 1):

As h tends to 0, the whole thing does not (usually) become undefined. Consider, for example, case f(x)=x. You will see that the fraction gives you 1, and it is quite defined.

Comment: The quantity $\frac{h}{h}=1$ only when $h\neq 0$. This gives a graph that is a horizontal line of height one with a gap at the point $(0,1)$. You can however meaningfully fill that gap in in only one nice way. Filling or fixing such gaps is intuitively what a limit is about.

Answer (score 1):

Note that the limit is used *because* naively setting $h=0$ does not work.
Try a simple example, such as $f(x)=x^2$. Then $f(x+h)-f(x)=(x+h)^2-x^2=2xh+h^2$. This can nicely be divided by $h\ne0$, resulting in $2x+h$; and now taking the limit as $h\to 0$ is really as simple as plugging in $h=0$.

$$\lim_{h\to0}\frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h} = \lim_{h\to0}\frac{(x+h)^2-x^2}{h} = \lim_{h\to0}\frac{2xh+h^2}{h} = \lim_{h\to0}(2x+h) = 2x.$$

Comment: You divided through by h and were left with 2x+h, so how is it you end up with just 2x?

Comment: don't forget that $h$ tends to zero!

Comment: but it still exists right? it may be small, very small, but it still has value does it not? Could you explain in layman's terms why it has disappeared?

Comment: It disappeared, because $2x$ is what $2x+h$ tends to.